# onItemclick of a fragment replace another fragment on same activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

on main activity i am calling a fragment

```
MenuFragment menufragment = new MenuFragment();
FragmentManager frm = getSupportFragmentManager();
frm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.**content_frame**, menufragment).commit();
```

In MenuFragment's onItemClick listener i am calling a another fragment ,i want to replace second fragment on main Activity id **content_frame** how can i achieve it

Comment: your question have duplication.. whatever you have already acheive it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager frm = getactivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
frm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.**content_frame**, secondfragment).commit();
```